# How to Combine And Add The Quantity,Price,Total Of Same Index In Listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to create a listbox that looks like receipt:

Here's how I would like it to look:

[image: how i like to do it]

But I have some problem with the spaces between the Name and quantity, they are not aligned. This is what I get:

[image: my listbox :/]

Does anyone have a solution for me please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal code sample that shows the code you need to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Use rich text box .We can create a RichTextBox control using a Forms designer at design-time or using the RichTextBox class in code at run-time.

```
RichTextBox dynamicRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();
```

then you can create two columns using 'padRight' function.

```
for(int i = 0; i<receipt.Length; i++)
        {
            String s1 = receipt[i, 0].PadRight(50);
            String s2 = receipt[i, 1].PadRight(50);
            ListBox1.item.add(  s1 + s2);
        }
```

Comment: but in rich box i cant choose the item and remove it if nedded .

Comment: then you can use multi column List box. you can enable multi column list box by     listbox1.MultiColumn = true;
and then instead of txtBox.Text = s1 + s2;  use     listBox1.Items.Add(s1 + s2);

Comment: i am using wpf , i dont have the option for multi coulumn like you said , d u know how can i do it ?

Comment: You can use datagrid view rather than list box. Both look similar and you have specific controls on both columns.